# Can't get the shape I want when creating an array from a Python list & TypeError with sort

Tags: python, numpy

When i specify the 'dtype' when creating an array i get a different shape than when i don't specify 'dtype'.

I have this code below where i only want the function np.sort() to sort taking 'factor' and 'var' as parameters, not 'data'.
Because inside 'data' i have 'None' values.
When i run this code i get this: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
But when i substitute 'None' with any 'int' the code runs as expected.

How can i make the code not to consider 'data' when sorting and/or not to break with 'None' values inside the list.

Code:

```
>>> hzhDtype = [('factor', float), ('var', int), ('data', list)]
>>> values = [
...     (3.82, 21, ['foo1', None, None, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.91, 21, ['foo1_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.91, 21, ['foo1_GT', 'foo3', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.91, 21, ['foo1_GT', 'foo4', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.91, 21, ['foo1_GT', 'foo5', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.55, 21, ['foo1_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g2', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g1', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.0, 2, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g2', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo2_GT', 'foo6', 1, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (2.0, 4, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.0, 4, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (0.5, 1, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (5.0, 5, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (5.0, 5, ['foo3_GT', 'foo1', 2, 3, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (2.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (2.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g2', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo5', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo5', 2, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (1.0, 1, ['foo4_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g2', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo1', 2, 2, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo2', 3, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo3', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo3', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g2', 'x', 0, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (2.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo5_GT', 'foo6', 1, 1, 'g1', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (4.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo1', 2, 1, 'g2', 'x', None, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo2', 3, 2, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo2', 3, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo3', 1, 2, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo3', 1, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 1]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo5', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', 1, 0]),
...     (3.0, 3, ['foo6_GT', 'foo5', 2, 2, 'g1', 'x', None, 1])
...         ]
>>> # this is the shape i want, but i can't sort it.
>>> arr = np.array(values)
>>> arr.shape
(55,3)
>>> np.sort(arr, axis=0)[::-1]
>>> *** TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
>>>
>>> # here i have the dtype i want but not the shape i want
>>> arr2 = np.array(values, dtype=hzhDtype)
>>> arr2.shape()
(55,)
>>> np.sort(arr2, order=['factor', var'])[::-1]
*** TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
>>> # i don't know why it look at the third column ('data') if i only want it to order considering 'factor' & 'var'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd case makes `structured array`, with 3 fields, not 3 columns.  If is 1d, not 2d.  You may need to read the `structured array` docs a bit more carefully.

As for the sort problem, re(read) `np.sort`:

```
order : str or list of str, optional
    When `a` is an array with fields defined, this argument specifies
    which fields to compare first, second, etc.  A single field can
    be specified as a string, and not all fields need be specified,
    but unspecified fields will still be used, in the order in which
    they come up in the dtype, to break ties.
```

It says "unspecified fields will still be used".

Looks like we can get around the `None` comparison problem by using `argsort`:

```
In [35]: idx=np.argsort(arr[['factor','var']])
In [36]: idx
Out[36]: 
array([19, 14, 13, 12, 11,  9, 15,  8,  6,  7, 18, 28, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32,
       27,  1,  2,  3,  4, 22, 23, 24, 25, 10, 44, 16, 17,  5, 51, 52, 49,
       46, 45, 42, 43, 50, 41, 54, 39, 38, 37, 53, 40,  0, 36, 35, 34, 47,
       48, 33, 21, 20])
In [37]: arr1=arr[idx]
```